# How to create a custom UILabel for Accessibility's Dynamic Text Sizing

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, dynamic-type-feature

I have a custom UILabel class that automatically scales the font using a font metric and size that's chosen by the user through Settings > General > Accessibility > Larger Text:

```
import UIKit

class AccessibilityLabel: UILabel {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        font = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: font)
        adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    }
}
```

In our existing, fairly large project, this works great.

**Where it does not work is where the font is set in code. When the font is set in code it removes the scaling.** We *could* go through and change all the code where we set the font to scale it. And maybe this is the best/only way.

But I was wondering if anyone knew of a way I could override the `font` property of the `UILabel` so it scales it if not already scaled and so doesn't create an endless loop. Basically, some solution where we would not have to go through our existing code and update multiple places. Just make the change in one place (in the UILabel).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did in a blank project *{Xcode 11, iOS 13}* containing only one label:

```
class AccessibilityLabel: UILabel {

    private var _font: UIFont?
    override var font: UIFont? {
        get { return _font }
        set { _font = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: newValue!) }
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    
        self.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    }
}
```

Then, I changed the font programmatically in my `ViewController` as follows:

```
//@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: AccessibilityLabel!
myLabel.font = UIFont(name: "NoteWorthy", size: 20.0)
```

... to get the results in different size text hereafter:
[image]
[image]
[image]

If I perfectly understood your problem, I think this solution should help you **making the UILabel custom only in one place without going through your existing code**.

... otherwise, just let me know if there's something I misunderstood, please.